How to import oneOf from Yup?
I used import * as Yup from "yup"; just to get me started but the vee-validate documentation says that I should only import what I'm using from yup because of the bundle size.
So then I switched from import * as Yup from "yup";
To: import {object, string } from 'yup'
And then the oneOf method stopped working and I dont know how to import it.
I also tried importing Schema but it still didn't work.

the oneOf method stopped working how are you using oneOf?

This is all core schema that you can import from yup
import { mixed, string, number, boolean, bool, date, object, array, ref, lazy, } from 'yup';

You can use oneOf by call mixed, like this
let schema = mixed().oneOf(['jimmy', 42]);

